# product of Matrices notation meaning

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to workout what the meaning of the notation is below.
$D$ is a matrix and it is the product from $1$ to $n$.  However, the $k(i)$ notation of the matrix and the subsequent $k:(1,2,....n) \to (1,2,...n)$ is confusing and need clarification.

$$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^n D_{k(i)}
$$
where
$$
k: ({1,2,....n}) \rightarrow  (1,2,.....n) 
$$

$D$ is a matrix and a product form $i$ to $n$ (without the $k$), but in this notation is it the product of $D$ matrix where $k$ is $n:1$?

Comment: Is that $=$ really meant to be there? If yes, what are the factors? Do you mean $D_{k(i)}$ or $D_k(i)$?

Comment: the = is not meant to be there, and it is the former $$ D_{k(i)} $$

Comment: Do you have any context where the notation came from? I have the feeling you are missing a crucial part of the formula involving the product.

Comment: Yes, the context is two diagonal matrices, $$ D_{1}, D_{2}$$ where $$ D_{1}D_{2} = D_{2}D_{1}$$ this equals$$ \prod\limits_{i=1}^n D_{i}$$

Comment: Are you sure it's not $n$ diagonal matrices with $D_iD_j = D_jD_i$ for all $i,j$?

Comment: building off of $$ D_{1}D_{2}=D_{2}D_{1}$$, but yes, that is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

For square matrices, the (generally non-commutative) product can be defined as usual

$$\prod_{i=1}^n A_i = A_1 A_2 \ldots A_n$$
In your specific case the matrices commute pairwise so the result doesn't depend on the order of multiplication ($k$ ist most likely a permutation)

---

Now given $n$ diagonal matrices $D_i,\ i=1..n$, we can see that
$$D_i D_j = D_j D_i \quad\forall i,j$$
So given a transposition $\tau_{i, i+1} \in S^n$ we can see that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n D_k = D_1 D_2 \ldots D_i D_{i+1} \ldots D_n = D_1 D_2 \ldots D_{i+1} D_i \ldots D_n = \prod_{k=1}^n D_{\tau_{i,i+1}(k)}$$
Now use the fact that every permutation $\pi\in S^n$ can be written as a finite product of transpositions to see that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n D_k = \prod_{k=1}^n D_{\pi(k)} \quad\forall \pi\in S^n$$

The notation $D_{\pi(k)}$ is not specific to the context. It just means pick the $\pi(k)$-th matrix as the $k$-th factor, where $\pi$ is a permutation. For example if $\pi = \pmatrix{1&2&3&4\\2&4&1&3}$ then
$$\prod_{k=1}^4 D_{\pi(k)} = D_2 D_4 D_1 D_3$$

Comment: @jliu I have added a sketch of the proof to my answer. Note that $k$ must actually be a permutation of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, else the proposition is false.

Comment: I'm trying to demonstrate that because $D_1D_2 = D_2D_1$ for diagonal matrices of the same size then 
$$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^n D_{(i)} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n D_{k(i)}
$$
where
$$
k: ({1,2,....n}) \rightarrow  (1,2,.....n) and D_i is 1:n
$$  Because its a series of diagonal matrices, the product $D_i$ is commutable, however, the permutation of $D_{k(i)} $  means that for any matrix $D_p$ where p:{1,2,...n}, but what does the notation $D_{p(i)}$ represent?

Comment: @jliu I'm almost certain that $k(i)$ is just indexing of your family $\{D_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and no operation on the matrix itself. Also note that you can edit your comments within 5 minutes of posting.

Comment: AlexR, this is clear to me now, yes, I think my 5 minutes of editing time expired, which caused me to re-pose.  Thanks again.